# How to rewrite $\sin^4 \theta$ in terms of $\cos \theta, \cos 2\theta,\cos3\theta,\cos4\theta$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with writing $\sin^4 \theta$ in terms of $\cos \theta, \cos 2\theta,\cos3\theta, \cos4\theta$.

My attempts so far has been unsuccessful and I constantly get developments that are way to cumbersome and not elegant at all. What is the best way to approach this problem?

I know that the answer should be:

$\sin^4 \theta =\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\cos2\theta+\frac{1}{8}\cos4\theta$

Please explain how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know De Moivre's Theorem?

Comment: Using formulas $\cos{2a}=\cos^2{a}-\sin^2{a}$ and $\sin^2{a}+\cos^2{a}=1$ express $\sin^2{a}$ and $\cos^2{a}$ by $\cos{a}$. Then use these expressions.

Comment: Correction - by $\cos{2a}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sin^4 \theta &= (\sin^2\theta)^2\\ &= \left(\frac12-\frac12\cos(2\theta)\right)^2\\ &= \frac14 \left(1 - \cos(2\theta)\right)^2\\ &= \frac14\left(1 - 2 \cos(2\theta) + \cos^2(2 \theta)\right)\\ &= \frac14\left(1 - 2 \cos(2 \theta) + \frac12(\cos (4\theta) + 1)\right)\\ &= \frac14\left(\frac32 - 2\cos(2\theta) + \frac12\cos(4 \theta)\right)\\ &= \frac38 - \frac12\cos(2\theta) + \frac18\cos(4\theta).\end{align}$$

Comment: I fixed some sign errors for you, and redid the layout. Take a look and see how I did it.

Comment: thanks, having a look now :)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! This was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Write

$$\sin^4{\theta} = \left ( \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2 i} \right )^4$$

and use the binomial theorem.

$$\begin{align}\left ( \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2 i} \right )^4 &= \frac{1}{16} (e^{i 4 \theta} - 4 e^{i 2 \theta} + 6 - 4 e^{-i 2 \theta} + e^{-i 4 \theta}) \\ &= \frac{1}{8} (\cos{4 \theta} - 4 \cos{2 \theta} + 3)\end{align}$$

Item of curiosity: the [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) are defined such that

$$T_n(\cos{\theta}) = \cos{n \theta}$$

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer! Not the solution I was looking for but maybe the easiest one of them.

Comment: Hopefully you learned something new.  Also check out the Chebyshev polynomials; they are really nifty and useful.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Start by noting $\sin^4 (\theta)=\left(\sin^2(\theta)\right)\cdot\left(\sin^2(\theta)\right)$. Then use  the double angle formula derived by $\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=1-2\sin^2 (\theta)$ so $$\sin^2(\theta)={1\over 2}\cdot\left(1-\cos(2\theta)\right)$$ and you now plug into the factors of  $\sin^4 (\theta) $, and use the double angle formula for $\cos^2(2\theta) $ to get the required answer.

Answer (score 2):

By repeatedly applying the formulas
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin(x)\sin(y)&=&{1\over2}\left[\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)\right]\\[5pt]
\sin(x)\cos(y)&=&{1\over2}\left[\sin(x-y)+\sin(x+y)\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
you will see how to write odd powers of sine as a linear combination of sines,
 and even powers of sine as a linear combination of cosines.